# AutoDeploy SQL changes with TeamCity (alternative to Redgate?)

Tags: .net, sql-server, svn, teamcity

I'm creating CI and Auto Deployment for .NET applications (source controlled with SVN) for our testing environment with TeamCity and all is going well. I am at the stage where I want to automate the execution of db scripts. I've done some searching and read several articles, such as http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/02/automated-database-releases-with.html (troyhunt's blogs have been invaluable!), and many seem to point at using RedGate software to manage and deploy changes. I am a bit apprehensive to let a new tool handle script generation so am wondering if there are other accepted methods out there worth investigating.

Our current standards for solution design include a Project containing DB related files like our orm db. It also contains a series of folders which contain our change scripts as illustrated below.

```
MySolution
 > MySolution.Data
    > 3.0 Scripts
       * 01 - UpdateUserTable.sql
       * 02 - UpdateRoleTable.sql
    > 3.1 Scripts
       * 01 - CreateJobTable.sql
       * 02 - InsertJobTypes.sql
       * 03 - AndSoOn.sql
```

I believe this structure is important as although we want to auto deploy to our testing environment upon checkin, we deploy actual release far less frequently and I'm not sure if RedGate's compare tools could handle the level of changes that sometimes happen. That's why I'm much more comfortable using version folders for the scripts and then incrementing the minor upon release to keep the script versions neatly contained.

Having this pre-existing structure, I was inclined to keep it and add a TeamCity build definition which could apply db scripts upon successful deployments. I imagined I could get TeamCity to identify newly added .sql files to SVN within the expected path and then execute these on the server, but perhaps I was expecting too much out of the box. I have implemented this sort of solution in the past with TFS and MSBUILD and custom build steps, but am totally new to the TeamCity way.

Is there already a process of achieving something like this? It seems to me to be quite a normal implementation, I've just not been able to find out how yet. Or is the RedGate solution the standard we should be going for?

Comment: What ORM framework are you using?

Comment: We typically use entity framework

Answer (score 4):

I read that same Troy Hunt article 2 years ago. It was a revelation, and I quickly got us up and running with SQL Source Control + SQL Compare + TC.  This was a great solution, but there are/were a few things that didn't work like I wanted.  Chief among them was that SQL Source Control does not (or did not) play well with branch/merge strategies.  Additionally, SQL Source Control was an out-of-band process that required developer training, adoption, and awareness of its quirks.  It never took root.  Our team ultimately moved away from RedGate in favor of TeamCity-driven Entity Framework migrations and we haven't looked back.

To your immediate question: I think that what you're trying to do here is possible, although I don't think it's necessarily TeamCity's job to look for newly added SQL scripts.  Red Gate and Entity Framework both identify the most recently deployed script/migration in the database itself, and reference that when determining where it should start applying changes.  You could store a similar value ('3.0') in your database, or as a TC build parameter, and then use powershell to iterate over newer folders and apply the latest scripts with *sqlcmd*.

You might consider looking at EF-based migrations though, especially if you've adopted the code-first model.  If you're interested, I can update this answer to talk more about how we do that.

**UPDATE:**

EF code-first migrations work by capturing a discrete set of DB schema changes in a migration class.  This class has an `Up` and a `Down` method that can apply/reverse that particular batch of schema changes.  This is more or less equivalent to how Ruby and others do it.

When you make a change to your Entity model (add a table, remove a column, change constraints, etc.), you create a new migration class by invoking `Add-Migration <DescriptionOfSchemaChange>` in the Package Manager Console.  This will generate new class named `<timestamp>_<DescriptionOfSchemaChange>.cs`. You can then apply that migration locally by invoking `Update-Database`.  Entity Framework manages the nuts and bolts for you, but you can inject arbitrary SQL into a migration step as needed.  PluralSight offers a [great course](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/efmigrations) covering these concepts.

The migration is managed by an executable, `migrate.exe`, that is deployed as part of the Entity Framework NuGet package.  In TeamCity, you can use `migrate.exe` to run a migration against a specified database.  First, you must copy `migrate.exe` local to the assembly that holds your migration classes.  Then you simply run `migrate.exe` against that assembly with the DB connection string as a parameter.  The working directory is that of the migration assembly.

`copy ..\..\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\migrate.exe .`

`migrate.exe ASSEMBLY.dll /connectionString="CONNECTION_STRING" /connectionProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

Comment: I'm investigating the powershell route you brought up. But I am curious about your EF-based migrations (I don't actually know anything about that approach).

Comment: The EF Migration solution (although sounds great) didn't really suit our needs, so being the tinker I am, I decided to take a voyage down making my own custom solution for this. I'll post an answer and may even make a blog about it.

Comment: We are using the same approach, but recently (after upgrading to EF6) we are experiencing OutOfMemory Errors during migrations in TC. Did you encounter this?

Answer (score 3):

After much searching and learning about how I might achieve my goal, I decided to just go ahead and write my own console application that does this for me. I'll lay down the basic steps here and may flesh them out in more detail later.

**DatabaseRevisionUpdater (The Console App)**

1. Using SVNSharp, DatabaseRevisionUpdater hooks into our SVN Server
   and reads SQL Script files into memory from a specified SVN Revision range.
2. Within .NET created Transaction, the app then reads through the script files one by one. If any errors are encountered running these scripts, the transaction is rolled back and the app exits with an error code of -1.
3. The target database should contain some new logging tables which are written to when updates are made. A version table tracks which revisions were made, successful and failed. A separate table contains information about the each script run for this revision request (with statuses Successful, Failed, and Skipped).
4. When future updates are made, the database's version is determined from the tables in Step 3. If the request intersects any previous successful updates, the update will not go ahead as it assumes its already been applied. The SVN Update Revision From can also be determined from these tables.

**TeamCity Integration**

- A Build Step is added of Runner type: Command Line
- Working Directory is the directory on the build server containing my console app
- Run: Custom script (Don't use executable with parameters as it doesn't seem to cope with arguments containing double quotes, like my dbConnectionString)
- Custom script: the executable followed by the arguments targeting my db. Arguments include svnUsername, svnPassword, svnPath, databaseConnectionString, and most importantly, RevisionTo. I use %build.vcs.number.APP_ID% to get the current build's revision number for this.

**Bonus usage - Updating disconnected databases**

This all works fine for our testing environment, but our live environment sits on an isolated network that does not have access to svn or the internet (for security reasons). With my console app, I use a few different Modes. The mode describe above is Direct Update, which is an all in one solution. It determines the DB current version by looking at its log tables, it polls SVN for all the updates since up till the revision you specify, it runs them against the target database and updates its logging tables accordingly. For our live environment, I added a couple of extra modes. Export and Import.

- Export is used to get scripts from SVN within a revision range. It then saves them to an XML file. It does not care about the target db at all.
- Import is used to import an XML Data file and apply updates within it to a target database. It cares about the version compatibility but has nothing to do with SVN any more.

That is essentially my solution. Nothing out of the box, but it works like a charm. I can make TeamCity interact with it nicely and use Console output to verbosely describe the process making it as transparent as possible. TeamCity reports all this output in its build logs and also fails or succeeds depending on my return code being 0 or something else.

Being a week long journey, I decided to do a little blog post detailing how I got here in case anyone else is interested: https://andrekriegler.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/auto-deploy-database/

Answer (score 0):

At Red Gate we're currently working on what we're calling "migrations v2". This is a database deployment technology that uses both the schema comparison methodology as well as allowing users to specify their own scripts, for example in data motion situations.

There's a [series of web pages](http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/MV2/Migrations+V2) that describe this better, as well as [a GoogleGroup forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/red-gate-migrations).

Let me know if you have any questions about how this functions.